# How to get the location for API 23 in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, location

**Project API requirements: API 23+.**
Location details are available and they work for API 26+, but for API 23 don't.

I have just read the article [Get user's location in android API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934318/get-users-location-in-android-api-23)

However, tried different solutions and still have no result. What could be the reason?

```
class TabFragment1 : Fragment() {
    var lat: Double = 0.0
    var long: Double = 0.0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    activity?.let {}
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false)
    val spinner1 = v.spinnerCategory as Spinner
    val buttonSearch = v.buttonSearch as Button

    // Search button
    buttonSearch.setOnClickListener {

        // GET LOCATION
        val g = this.activity?.let {
                it1 -> geo(it1)
        }

        if (g != null) {
            activity?.let {

                if (g[0] == 0.0 && g[1] == 0.0) {

                    println(" g result ${g[0]}")
                    alert(getString(R.string.error_no_location))

                    // Request location updates
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        var permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                            permissions = permissions.plus(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                        }
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, permissions, 0)
                    }
                } else {

                    // segue
                    val intent = Intent(it, PostTableViewActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("long", g[1].toString())
                    intent.putExtra("lat", g[0].toString())
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("TurnOn Geolocation!")
        }
    }
    return v
}
```

**geo.kt:**

```
fun geo(context: Context): DoubleArray? {

    val locationManager: LocationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    val providers: List<String> = locationManager.getProviders(true)
    var location: Location? = null

    for (i in providers.size - 1 downTo 0) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                println(" NO PERMS?? ")
            var permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                permissions = permissions.plus(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, permissions,0)
            return null
        }

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providers[i])
        if (location != null)
            break
    }

    val gps = DoubleArray(2)
    if (location != null) {
        println(" GEO FUNC has lat, long - ?? ${location.latitude}, ${location.longitude}")

        gps[0] = location.latitude
        gps[1] = location.longitude
    }
    return gps
}
```

*API 23 console result:*

> I/System.out:  g result 0.0

*API 26 console result:*

> I/System.out:  GEO FUNC has lat, long - ?? 37.421998333333335, -122.08400000000002

**Manifest**:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
>
> <!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
> ```

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` routinely returns `null`, and you do not seem to be doing anything to request location updates. If you want a guaranteed location, do not use `getLastKnownLocation()`. Use methods like [`requestSingleLocation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestSingleUpdate(java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)).

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know how to clean cache on the device? (to make fresh start and see when the device asks for permissions)

Comment: You can remove permissions or clear data via your app's screen in the system Settings app.

Comment: @CommonsWare **Unresolved reference: requestSingleLocation.**
There is also ... getCurrentLocation() Should I use this? Do you have an example, please?)

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo in the comment -- it is `requestSingleUpdate()`. You can click the link in the original comment to see the JavaDocs. `getCurrentLocation()` is also fine, but it is only available on Android 11+. [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/PermissionCheck) demonstrates `getCurrentLocation()`. I do not think I have a recent example showing `requestSingleUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Only this works for API == 23*

**1. build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
```

**2. permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**3. context -> gps[latitude, longitude]**

```
private fun requestCurrentLocation(context: Context): DoubleArray? {
    val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient by lazy {
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    }
    var cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource()
    val gps = DoubleArray(2)

    // Check Fine permission
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Main code
        val currentLocationTask: Task<Location> = fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(
            PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,
            cancellationTokenSource.token
        )

        currentLocationTask.addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Location> ->
            val result = if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val result: Location = task.result
                gps[0] = result.latitude
                gps[1] = result.longitude
                "Location (success): ${result.latitude}, ${result.longitude}"
            } else {
                val exception = task.exception
                "Location (failure): $exception"
            }

            println("getCurrentLocation() result: $result")
        }
    } else {
        // Request fine location permission (full code below).
    }
    return gps
}
```